# Running a php file in a batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I'm trying to run a php file within a batch file. I have the folder for php.exe within the same directory as the bat.

```
set addLocation="%cd%\test.php"
set exeLocation="%cd%\php\php.exe"

start "run" "%cd%\php\php.exe" "%location%"

pause
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean a Windows `.bat` / `.cmd` file

Comment: @RiggsFolly bat file is a batch file isn't it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just want it to call the php.exe so it can execute the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this method myself

Batch file called `xxxx.cmd`

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\folder\with\phpexe
CD \path\to\php_source
php file.php
```

The php folder is added to the PATH only for the duration of this command windows existance

Comment: I get this error - 
`'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Well you have to replace `C:\path\to\folder\with\phpexe` with the **actual path where you installed PHP**

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following code:

1. To change the directory -

   `set path = D:\Workspace` 

   `CD /D %path%`
2. To run the php file -

   `php file.php`

This code will work well.
Thank you.